# Series vs parallel for microphones (electric guitars)

Tags: microphone, parallel, series

I want to create a passive "mixer", with which I can connect two of my guitars to one amplifier, so basically one with two 6,3" input jacks and one for output.

For passives without a transformer as far as I know I have two options:
Connecting them parallel or series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsMr8V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Which one should I use and why? If there is no specific, what are the advantages of each?
Won't parallel produce too much voltage and damage my pre-amp or amp?

(PS: I know that the volume knobs will affect both guitars, but that doesn't matter for me.)

Comment: Is this an electret microphone or a guitar pickup? Parallel will work for electret microphones, at the cost of some volume and quality.

Comment: @pjc50 It is a guitar pickup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is two separate guitars, pretty much your only option is a parallel connection  That's because these are unbalanced, hi-impedance signals.  If you were in fact to wire these in series, touching any of the metal associated with the top guitar's wiring(metal connector shell, etc) would cause hum and other noises.

Pretty much any of the passive audio mixers that I've seen just connect the hot signal from each guitar to the top end of a potentiometer with all of the ground connections connected together and to the bottom end of each pot.  The wiper connections of each pot go to a summing resistor (about 100k for guitar signals) and then to the output.  Pot values for a passive guitar mixer would be somewhere between 100k to 1 Megohm, audio taper.

A passive mixer such as I have described has a lot of flaws but they *do* work. And they will allow you to adjust the level from each guitar individually.

Comment: While I said mixer it will just combine the two signals, so no potentiometers will be necessary. But thanks for the additional info, might prove useful later and for others.

Answer (score 0):

"If this is two separate guitars, pretty much your only option is a parallel connection That's because these are unbalanced, hi-impedance signals."

That's wrong, the question was about microphones on Guitar cabs and not guitar signal.
The Microphones outputs are balanced.

I've seen people doing it with a paralel connection, but Series sounds better to me, and it seems there's less impedance mismatch.

Check this thread on the subject:

https://groupdiy.com/index.php?topic=60308.msg765021#msg765021

Most people do it in paralel because they dont even know you can connect/sum two mics in series.
Try both and check wich you prefer

Comment: Nope, it's guitar pickups, not microphones. See OP's comments: "*@pjc50 It is a guitar pickup.* – akaltar Feb 16 '15 at 17:15". Welcome to EE.SE. Unfortunately many questions are poorly worded and we have to pry the relevant information out of the authors. In this case he added it in the comments but didn't update the question. Just a note: "Guitar", "Microphones" and "Series" are not brand names or proper nouns so they don't get capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect two or more guitars in parallel, I would suggest adding a 100K resistor in series with each output before joining them.  The output impedance of a typical guitar will vary depending upon its volume-pot position, but will drop to almost nothing if the volume pot is set to 0.  Adding a resistor in series with a guitar's output will reduce the signal level from that guitar when its pot is turned up, but will reduce the amount of signal the guitar steals from the other when its pot is turned down.  If you don't have a resistor, turning either guitar's volume to 0 will kill the output from both guitars.